# Difference between "reverse" and "-property" with orderBy in ngRepeat?

Tags: angularjs

In the AngularJS doc for "orderBy", the description of the "string" property is as follows (with my emphasis):

> An Angular expression which evaluates to an object to order by, such as 'name' to sort by a property called 'name'. **Optionally prefixed with + or - to control ascending or descending sort order (for example, +name or -name).**

The description of the "reverse" property is as follows:

> Reverse the order the array.

So what should be the difference between using "-property" and "reverse"?  Should both of these do the same thing?

For my test case, I can't get "reverse" to do anything.  I constructed a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ks6xTfJxXEQnmVmtJd3M?p=preview) with three ngRepeats.  The first one is without any ordering, the second one ordered with "reverse", and the last ordered with "-property".  The latter does what I expect, the former doesn't appear to do anything.

The documentation is clearly ambiguous, but I would have expected "reverse" and "-property" to do the same thing.  What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [manual](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) you'll find `reverse` to be of type `boolean`. Which indicates that it's value will be looked up in the current scope or is meant to be literal. Simply plucking in `reverse` will then evaluate to `undefined` (because it's probably not defined on the scope) which is falsy and thus `reverse` has no effect. Use a scope value or a litteral (true, false) to see it's effect.

The reason to have two ways of reversing the sort order is because it's hard to to change the `+/-` through data-binding techniques, while it's easy to simply refer to a scope variable using the reverse expression. And thus change the order through data-binding (e.g. button clicks which change a scope variable, which is actually an example on the manual page).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `orderBy:'lastRun':reverse` put quotes around 'reverse': `orderBy:'lastRun':'reverse'`